# R: histogram of proportion of a value of a categorical variable (instead of many histograms for each value)

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a continuous variable ('amount') and a categorical variable ('fate', which has two values - Good or Bad):

```
> loans[c('amount', 'fate')]
# A tibble: 34,655 x 2
   amount fate 
    <dbl> <chr>
 1   8000 Bad  
 2  11000 Good 
 3  20000 Good 
 4  10000 Bad  
 5  20000 Good 
 6  15250 Good 
 7   7800 Good 
 8  18000 Good 
 9   5600 Good 
10  24000 Bad  
# ... with 34,645 more rows
```

I could plot histograms for counts or frequencies for the two categories easily:

```
loans %>% gf_histogram(..count.. ~ amount) %>% gf_facet_grid(fate ~ .)
```

Result:

[image]

But this is not what I want. Instead, for each bucket I want to plot the proportion of either Good or Bad values, relative to all occurrences in that bucket (Good + Bad).

In other words, I want the histogram of, say, Bad / (Good + Bad) data points in each bucket, instead of separate histograms for Good and Bad.

Ideally, this should happen with as few transformations as possible to the data frame.

How do I do that?

**EDIT**: Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(ggformula)
library(dplyr)

tt <- structure(list(amount = c(8000, 11000, 20000, 10000, 20000, 15250, 
7800, 18000, 5600, 24000, 3600, 10000, 16000, 35000, 17225, 19500, 
4000, 9475, 24000, 6000, 8000, 13100, 4700, 10000, 18500, 20800, 
9000, 17500, 23550, 21000, 20950, 16975, 12000, 9000, 12000, 
3850, 24175, 2250, 14425, 7200, 6150, 30000, 12000, 10000, 8000, 
2400, 10000, 35000, 27050, 8500, 9600, 5650, 5600, 28000, 8325, 
3000, 16800, 2000, 21000, 4500, 14525, 15000, 20000, 22475, 2200, 
15000, 30000, 15000, 9000, 12000, 13000, 2000, 10000, 33600, 
20000, 18000, 15000, 35000, 20000, 24000, 12500, 5000, 13475, 
12000, 18625, 1200, 13000, 12000, 12000, 17000, 22800, 17000, 
29975, 16750, 18000, 9000, 8400, 15000, 10000, 21000), fate = c("Bad", 
"Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", 
"Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", 
"Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", 
"Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", 
"Good")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

tt %>% gf_histogram(..density.. ~ amount) %>% gf_facet_grid(fate ~ .)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

tt <- structure(list(amount = c(8000, 11000, 20000, 10000, 20000, 15250, 
7800, 18000, 5600, 24000, 3600, 10000, 16000, 35000, 17225, 19500, 
4000, 9475, 24000, 6000, 8000, 13100, 4700, 10000, 18500, 20800, 
9000, 17500, 23550, 21000, 20950, 16975, 12000, 9000, 12000, 
3850, 24175, 2250, 14425, 7200, 6150, 30000, 12000, 10000, 8000, 
2400, 10000, 35000, 27050, 8500, 9600, 5650, 5600, 28000, 8325, 
3000, 16800, 2000, 21000, 4500, 14525, 15000, 20000, 22475, 2200, 
15000, 30000, 15000, 9000, 12000, 13000, 2000, 10000, 33600, 
20000, 18000, 15000, 35000, 20000, 24000, 12500, 5000, 13475, 
12000, 18625, 1200, 13000, 12000, 12000, 17000, 22800, 17000, 
29975, 16750, 18000, 9000, 8400, 15000, 10000, 21000), fate = c("Bad", 
"Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", 
"Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", 
"Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", 
"Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", 
"Good")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

tt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = amount, fill = fate)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "fill", bins = 30) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) +
  labs(
    y = "Proportion",
    x = "Amount",
    fill = "Fate"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I added an example to my question now. Back to your reply: I can do stacked bars just fine (tt %>% gf_histogram(fill =~ fate, ..density.. ~ amount)) but that's not what I want. What I want is, for each bucket of 'amount' values, to show the proportion of Good occurences, relative to all occurrences in that bucket. Don't show Good and Bad for each bucket, just show Good / (Good + Bad), single value.

Comment: See update. Is that more in line with what you are looking for?

Comment: Got it! tt %>% gf_histogram(fill =~ fate, position = 'fill', ~ amount) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is very much *not* a histogram at that point. You're really just describing a bar chart. You can have ggplot calculate the proportions in bins for you using `stat_summary_bin`. For example

```
ggplot(tt) + 
  stat_summary_bin(aes(amount, as.numeric(fate=="Bad")), fun="mean", geom="bar") + 
  labs(y="Proportion Bad")
```

[image]